# How to iterate over individual and merged values in an R for loop function?

Tags: r, loops, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I am producing reports across a number of individual departments using a for loop similar to the below:

```
report_loop <- function() {
  
  pacman::p_load(tidyverse)
  
  df1 <- data.frame(Dept = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'G'),
                    Value = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4, 5, 7))
  
  for (id in c('A','B','C','D','E','F','G')) {
    
    Spec <- id
  
  rmarkdown::render("C:/R/Reprex/Template.rmd", 
                    output_dir = "C:/R/Reprex",
                    output_file = paste0('Report_', str_to_title(id), '.html'))    
  }
}

report_loop()
```

The report_loop function renders a flexdashboard "Template.rmd" file which itself contains various tables/plots that are all filtered for the looped department, similar to the below:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

{r setup, include=FALSE}

pacman::p_load(tidyverse)

## Column {data-width=650}

### Chart A

{r}

df1 %>% 
filter(Dept %in% Spec) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=Dept, y=Value)) +
  geom_col()
```

This has worked perfectly thus far, but I am now keen to merge departments... and that's where I've become unstuck. Using the above reprex, for example, lets say I want to generate just two reports instead of one for each of the seven departments. So for the first report I would just want Dept == A, but for the second report I would want to merge all remaining departments. I haven't yet been able to manage this, despite lots of playing around.

My hope was that I could just specify a list prior to running the loop, as follows...

```
report_loop2 <- function() {
  
  library(tidyverse)
  
  df1 <- data.frame(Dept = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'G'),
                    Value = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4, 5, 7))
  
  MergeDept <- list('B','C','D','E','F','G')
  
  for (id in c('A','MergeDept')) {
    
    Spec <- id
    
    rmarkdown::render("C:/R/Reprex/Template.rmd", 
                      output_dir = "C:/R/Reprex",
                      output_file = paste0('Report_', str_to_title(id), '.html'))    
  }
}

report_loop2()
```

... but evidently there is an issue with iterating over a group of values and I haven't been able to figure out why / fix thus far. Appreciate it's likely very simple, but not for me!

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: should you have `for (id in list(list('A'),MergeDept)) {` instead of `for (id in c('A','MergeDept')) {`.  That way in the rmd file `Spec` is a list not just the string `"MergeDept"`

Comment: Thanks for response, changing to the following:

report_loop2 <- function() {
  
  library(tidyverse)
  
  df1 <- data.frame(Dept = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'G'),
                    Value = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4, 5, 7))
  
  MergeDept <- list('B','C','D','E','F','G')
  
  for (id in list(list('A'),MergeDept)) {
    
    Spec <- id
    
    rmarkdown::render("C:/R/Reprex/Template.rmd", 
                      output_dir = "C:/R/Reprex",
                      output_file = paste0('Report_', str_to_title(id), '.html'))    
  }
}

Comment: returns: 

Error in if (!grepl("[.]html$", output_file)) knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.retina = NULL) : 
  the condition has length > 1
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In is.null(output_file) || is.na(output_file) :
  'length(x) = 6 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
2: In !inherits(output_file, "AsIs") && xfun::file_ext(output_file) ==  :
  'length(x) = 6 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
3: In length(x) > 0 && utils::file_test("-d", x) :
  'length(x) = 6 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that you were also using ID in the outfile title.  You could replace `str_to_title(id)` with `paste0(str_to_title(list("X","Y")), collapse="")`

Comment: Look at this though for better ways to set parameters in rmarkdown.  https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-6.html

Comment: George this works!! my only remaining issue is that the report output is now a single file being overwritten (as the 'id' is being used to create unique report names). Your suggestion of paste0(str_to_title(list("X","Y")), collapse="") doesn't contain the id, so presumably will always just cause the file to be overwritten?

Comment: OK, just used toString(id) to accomplish - George thanks so much for your help.

Comment: oops sorry I meant `id`, I was just testing it with `"X","Y"`

Answer (score 0):

George's comments attached to the question work.

Comment: That is great, but this is not an answer, please summarize what you have done and describe the solution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).